# how can I get users to add fields into a list where many fields are optional?

Tags: forms, input-fields, lists

I need to design a page to get user inputs in below format:

```
1. Item A (text)

 a. Sub-item (text)

 b. Upload photo for Sub-item (Browse and upload)

 c. Description for Sub-item (text)

2. Item B (text)

 a. Sub-item (text)

 b. Upload photo for Sub-item (Browse and upload)

 c. Description for Sub-item (text)
```

Only Item A, Item B, Item n.. are required. All other fields are optional. I like this to be in one page, heavy javascript to guide users.

I am thinking to show only one field for Item A, when users click on it, it show other field one by one through jQuery. All field should have Suggested Text, etc...

**But is there a suitable method for getting multiple user inputs through text in a list format that is not too intimidating for users?**

Comment: Can you give some further details. What context will this be in, will it be used on mobile devices? Does it have to look visually like a list?

Comment: It is on desktop and doesn't have to look like a list. Basically Item A is a Business Name, Sub-item is the Service or Product of that business, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not to use jQuery and display the form fully. Imagine if you are a user and you come to the form where there is 1 field. Great only 1 field to fill out that's easy! But every time you fill it in the new filed comes up. AAAAArgh! It would drive me crazy, especially if you have more than 1 of these.

Other alternative is to display 1 field and having something like "Describe your item" link under that would display all sub-items strait away. And then have a "Add an item" button if the user would like to add an extra item.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foHbdB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Also I'm a bit confused about the question in bold... are you talking about the form?

Comment: But what if the full form shows only ONCE when the Item A is clicked? That wouldn't be much annoying is it? The reason I am thinking about it is because showing everything will scare of users (Etsy does the "context" input display pretty well). Also I don't know if letting users to click on Describe your Item would consider "more work" (aka. fewer people will likely to do that although I like to get high percentage of people filling out the optional parts). Yes, my bold question is about the form.

Comment: I thought that sub items are not essential to complete the form. Why would 4 field form scare the user away?

Comment: Well, there could be Item C, Item B, etc... That would be a long list to enter. The ideal goal is to get users to fill in at least Item A and Item B with all sub-items.

Answer (score 0):

A common usage example for such pattern would be websites which maintains your profiles like Naukri.com, elance.com etc where you would click a link to Add an employment/Education/skill/language/certifications/licenses etc. They would give you a bunch of fields out of which only 1-2 will be mandatory and rest will be optional.

Assuming that all the fields are going to be same and if showing 4-5 fields at the same time is taking too much of real-estate in your context, then you could do the following

-- Show only mandatory fields with the Save button and 'More' link

-- On clicking 'More' link, other fields would be displayed

-- On clicking 'Save' button, show the data in a grid kind of layout (and recently saved data on top) along with a 'Add New' button.